# iOS App UILabel crashed when I change text size from iOS Settings Screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, text, uilabel

I have

```
@IBOutlet weak var onlineStatusLabel: UILabel!
```

declared in TableViewCell Class
My table view use static cells.
When I inside the app everything is ok, once I change text size setting in iOS setting screen and come back to my app, app crashes with this error:

appName/TableVC.swift:47: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

This is what I call from my TableVC:

```
import UIKit

class TableVC: UITableViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      //  super.tableView(tableView, willDisplay: cell, forRowAt: indexPath)
        guard let cell = cell as? CustomTableViewCell else { return }
        cell.onlineStatusLabel.textColor = .red // app crash here, this means that onlineStatusLabel is nil, but how???
        cell.onlineStatusLabel.text = "Text"
    }
}
```

CellView:

```
import UIKit

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var onlineStatusLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

[Image with code for TableVC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPS9t.png)

[Image with code for Cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dS8tW.png)

[Storyboard configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aksZH.png)

[Storyboard cell configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIpKq.png)

How it can be nil? How size change can react on UILabel?
Can you please suggest?

Comment: To me, this would imply that the system removes the existing elements from the view hierarchy and replaces them when when the text size is changed. *Hopefully* the system hooks up the outlets again after the change. But, since you have your outlet declared as `UILabel!`, if the system reloads the tableview during this state, it seems you would get a crash. Does it work if you declare your outlet as `UILabel?` and treat it as an optional?

Comment: @jnpdx , thanks  it works then, but system never reloads it again, and all info at this label is outdated.

Comment: What does "all info at this label is outdated" mean? I would assume that if you're just changing the text size, the text itself (ie the characters) wouldn't change, right? Do you *also* need to trigger a table refresh when the app comes back from the background?

Comment: No, I have some callbacks, that should change this label when for example "presence changed", when I change presence from other place this label is still nil. To fix it I need to force close the app. I can reproduce this only when I change text size from iOS settings screen.

Comment: Sounds like a tough issue to try to debug without us being able to see a [mre].

Comment: @jnpdx I have updated the question with reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing one method within cell class like this

```
public func setupLabel() {
    
    guard onlineStatusLabel != nil else {return}
    
    self.onlineStatusLabel.textColor = .red
    self.onlineStatusLabel.text = "Text"
}
```

And call that function with table view delegate method like this

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //  super.tableView(tableView, willDisplay: cell, forRowAt: indexPath)
    guard let cell = cell as? CustomTableViewCell else { return }
    cell.setupLabel()
}
```